# 二つの連結リストを結合させ、そのリストを表示させるプログラムです。やりたいことはできているのですが、最後、正常に終わりません。

Tags: c++

二つの連結リストを結合させ（一つの連結リストをもう片方の連結リストにつなげる）、その結合したリストを表示させるプログラムを作りたいです。

やりたいことはできているのですが、最後、正常に終わりません（0を返さない）。どうやら、appendメソッドがうまくいっていないようです。デバッグしたところsetPrevメソッドで永遠にループしてしまっているようです。

しかし、これが本当に問題なのか、そうだとしたら、どう解決したらいいかが分かりません。結合した連結リストをmain.cppで表示したところ、つながってはいるみたいです。

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TextClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int APPEND1 = 6;
    const int APPEND2 = 7;
    int counter = 0;
    char appendVals[APPEND1 + APPEND2] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'};

    TextClass first;
    for (int i = 0; i < APPEND1; i++)
    {
        first.addTail(appendVals[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    TextClass second;
    for (int i = 0; i < APPEND2; i++)
    {
        second.addTail(appendVals[counter]);
        counter++;
    }

    std::cout << "First list is " << first.displayList() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second list is " << second.displayList() << std::endl;

    first.append(second);
    std::cout << "First should now be a b c d e f g h i j k l m" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " and it actually is " << first.displayList() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Done appending a list\n" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**TextClass.cpp**

```
#include "TextClass.h"
#include <sstream>
//constructor
Link::Link(char letter, Link* next, Link* prev)
{
    value = letter;
    this->next = next;
    this->prev = prev;
}

//destructor
Link::~Link(){}

//return the value in the link
char Link::getValue(){return value;}

//set a new next address
void Link::setNext(Link* next){this->next = next;}

//set a new previous address
void Link::setPrev(Link* prev){this->prev = prev;}

// return the next address
Link* Link::getNext(){return this->next;}

// return the previous address
Link* Link::getPrev(){return this->prev;}


//constructor
TextClass::TextClass()
{
    //head and tail are set to nullptr
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

//destructor
TextClass::~TextClass()
{
    //call removeHead until head = nullptr;
    while(head != nullptr)
    {
        removeHead();
    }
}


//add value at tail
void TextClass::addTail(char letter)
{
    //if head == nullptr
    if(tail == nullptr)
    {
        //head and tail = new link
        head = tail = new Link(letter);
    }
        //else
    else
    {
        //create new link and insert it at tail
        Link* temp = new Link(letter, nullptr, tail);
        tail->setNext(temp);
        //change tail
        tail = temp;
    }
}


//return the contents of list
string TextClass::displayList()
{

    //create a variable that stores contents for string and stringstream
    string output;
    std::stringstream ss;
    //create a link that walks down the list and it starts from head
    Link* temp = head;
    //while the link != nullptr
    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        //copy the value in the link to stringstream
        ss << temp->getValue() << " ";
        //move the link forward
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }

    //copy the value in stringstream to string
    output = ss.str();

    //return the string
    return output;
}

//connects two lists
void TextClass::append(TextClass otherList)
{
    //create a link that stores the head of otherList
    Link* temp = otherList.head;

    //connect two links
    //tail next should point to head of otherLink
    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        addTail(temp->getValue());
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }

}

//remove head
void TextClass::removeHead()
{
    //save the link at head to delete later
    Link* temp = head;
    //update head
    head = head->getNext();
    //if head is null after update
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        //tail = nullptr
        tail = nullptr;
    }
        //else update prev of new link
    else
    {
        head->setPrev(nullptr);
    }
    //now delete the old link
    delete temp;
}
```

**TextClass.h**

```
#include <iostream>


using std::string;

class Link {
private:
    char value; //stores chat type value
    Link* next; //stores the address of next link
    Link* prev; //stores the address of previous link

public:
    Link(char letter, Link* next = nullptr, Link* prev = nullptr); //constructor
    ~Link(); //destructor
    char getValue(); //return the value in the link
    void setNext(Link* next); //set a new next address
    void setPrev(Link* prev); //set a new previous address
    Link* getNext(); // return the next address
    Link* getPrev(); // return the previous address
};


class TextClass {
private:
    Link* head; //track the head link of queue
    Link* tail; //track the tail link of queue
public:
    TextClass(); //constructor
    ~TextClass(); //destructor

    void addTail(char letter); //add value at tail
    string displayList(); // return the contents of list
    void append(TextClass otherList); //connects two lists
    void removeHead(); //remove head
};
```

Answer (score 0):

何をもって「正常」とするのか一言も書かれていませんので、どう直せば「あなたにとっての正解」なのか読者にはわかりません。読者の推定はあなたの期待通りとは限らないので・・・

まあとりあえずこの問題に関しては次の修正でいけそうな気がします。

誤： `void TextClass::append(TextClass otherList)`
正： `void TextClass::append(TextClass const& otherList)`
（ `TextClass.h` と `TextClass.cpp` の両方を修正）

誤だと `append()` の呼び出しの際に引数である `otherList` の複写（コピーコンストラクト）と破棄（デストラクト）が行われます。が、提示ソースには `TextClass` のコピーコンストラクタが提供されていません。そのため期待通りの動きをしていないのでしょう（何が正解かわからないので推測）

正だと複写が発生しないので破棄も発生せず、よって問題ないです。

ンでこの辺を詳しく解説すると結構長くなりそうです。ディープコピーとシャローコピーとかうんぬん。興味があれば別の質問を挙げてください。

Comment: たしかに、正直自分でもなぜシャロ―コピーでできてしまっているのだろうと思っていました。しかし、実際にはシャロ―コピーではうまくいってなかったのですね。ディープとシャロ―コピーの勉強のし直しが必要みたいですね。これを機にやり直してみます。ありがとうございました。